# Get rid of the label in a ModelForm?

Tags: django, forms, model, django-forms

So I'm trying to have field in my model for that are hidden but contain default values and can't be changed thus being hidden(are there more secure ways of having default fields that will always be a variable?) anyway when i use

```
username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

It only hides the actual input field and lets the label just be free on the html of the website so is there a way that I can get rid of the label that just freely floats around? and are there better ways of submitting say the username of the currently logged in user to the model?

Right now I'm using inital on the form like this:

```
USER=request.user
ref_create = CashtextsForm(initial={'username': USER})
```

is that secureish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user doesn't need to edit the form field, it's much better to not even include it in your model form- even a hidden form input can be manipulated by a user.

To remove it, just add it to the exclude tuple in the meta class of your model form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ('username',)
```

Then, to set `username` to the current user after they have submitted the form, you would use the following code after checking if `form.is_valid()`:

```
mymodel = form.save(commit=False)
mymodel.username = request.user
mymodel.save()
```

Comment: thanks. I figured hidden forms weren't very secure but i was unaware of commit=false. thanks for the help